# No module found [my_app] with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

This is my directory structure, in `/var/www`:

```
team_django
--team_db
---- __init__.py
-----settings.py
-----wsgi.py
```

My wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'team_db.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load`:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/local/py_ptracker/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py311.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/usr/local/py_ptracker"
```

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/vhost.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      mydomain
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/team_django/team_db/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/team_django/team_db>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `mod_wsgi` is enabled, as the vhost configuration, and everything gets loaded fine. I get this in the `error.log` though:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'team_db'
 [wsgi:error] [pid 225277] mod_wsgi (pid=225277): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/team_django/team_db/wsgi.py'., referer: ...
[wsgi:error] [pid 225277] mod_wsgi (pid=225277): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/team_django/team_db/wsgi.py'., referer: ....
```

Why isn't the `os.environ.setdefault` finding `team_db`? I've checked all permisions and I also set everything to 777, changing owners and group to www-data or root and all that; to no avail. I can't understand why it's not finding the team_db. Te server runs correctly with Django's runserver and also with the mod_wsgi-express runserver.

The mod_wsgi has been built with the same version of Python, within the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add

````
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/var/www/')
sys.path.append('/var/www/team_django')
sys.path.append('/var/www/team_django/team_db')```

to my .wsgi
````